# django cms add own model in admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I made new app named "pricing" (`manage.py startapp pricing`).
Frontend works fine. Now i want to add extra field in my django-cms admin, where user can store, change, add new values in Db for this app.
With few words: I want to register model from my app to django-cms admin. I want it to appears at bottom of admin page.

```
mycms:
   mysite
    static
    templates
    **pricing(my app)
        templates
        admin.py
        models.py
        test.py
        views.py**
    cms_plugins.py
    forms.py
    models.py
    settings.oy
    urls.py
    views.py
```

`pricing app`:

```
models.py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    introduction = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    offer_option = models.TextField()
    prop_one = models.TextField()
    prop_two = models.TextField()
    prop_three = models.TextField()
    price = models.TextField()
    period =  models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.offer_option
```

`views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render 
from django.utils import timezone from .models import Post

def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'post_list.html', {'posts': posts})
```

`admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models hefrom django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post

admin.site.register(Post)
```